# Accessing Apex rest class with OAuth 2.0 with Named Credential authentication mechanism

Tags: apex, callout, rest, oauth2, namedcredentials

I have been trying to implement Oauth 2.0 in my org and my requirement is to use Named credentials only when making a apex callout. I am using Named credentials, Oauth, Connected Apps and auth. provider to establish a connection with an external Salesforce org. The external org has exposed an apex class as REST service that I am trying to access using my org. I have followed the steps given in this link to setup everything :

http://manueltejeiro.com/2016/05/12/named-credentials-using-oauth/

Below are the setting at my end:

1. Connected App:[image]
2. Auth Provider:[image]
3. Named Credentials:[image]

I am trying to test hitting the service using the below code in execute anonymous. I used `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');` in the request header. On executing I get this error in response body - `[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredtional_name');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth {!$Credential.OAuthToken}'); 
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setTimeout(30000);
String JSONString = '{"AccountNumber":"65764556","AccountName":"xyz"}]}';
req.setBody(JSONString);
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);    
System.debug('Response Body===========' + res.getBody()); //  `[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`
```

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: You're using the Generate Authentication Header feature, so you shouldn't be setting your own.

Comment: Gotcha. That was not right to include the header again in the callout code.

Comment: @SfdcBat - When you completed the oAuth process did you use credential for the external org or your sandbox org?

Comment: I used my salesforce org credentials. I did not use external org information anywhere other than the Apex rest class endpoint URL.

Comment: If you are attempting to connect to an external system rest endpoint you need to use those credentials....

Comment: Thanks. I did login using the external system credentials now. I got error - [{"errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST"}] (System.HttpResponse[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405]) this time.

Comment: Wow it worked now. I was login in with my own credentials for Oauth instead of the external salesforce org's credentials.

Comment: Thank you both. I just appreciate how helpful you guys are in this community.

Comment: @Eric I want to clarify one thing. In my org's named credential I used external salesforce user's credential to login. In the salesforce document it says - Salesforce uses the OAuth protocol to allow users of applications to securely access data without having to reveal username and password credentials. My question - I am trying to understand since I am making an apex callout from my Org, why do I need to authenticate external org's user in named credentials. I feel my understanding is not in sync.

Comment: @SfdcBat  If the data you are accessing is in another org you need the credentials for that org. Would you use your orgs credentials if you were trying to login to the other org manually, no. If what you are trying to access is in your org then you would use those credentials

Comment: @Eric thanks I was confused because I created connected app, auth provider and named credential in my org and had to use only external system username when saving the named credentials. It seemed to me that since connected app is in my system I was trying to authenticate my system as the screen returned back to my org after I logged in but no it authenticated the access to external system.

Comment: Right. A connected app can be anywhere as long as you have the two keys. You could use same connected app to connect to my org if you had a user . All a connected app does is identify the app to the user using essentially a public and private key. It confused me at first as well I had like 6 connected apps until I realized I only needed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your credentials are set up correctly - You are missing the path on your endpoint

1. Edit and save your Named Credential to redo the oAuth process. If you can complete that then the Auth Provider is set up correctly
2. Endpoint is not correct but would not product the invalid session id, it would be a different error

   ```
   req.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredtional_name/services/apexrest/{YOURRETREQUESTNAMEHERE}');
   ```

To validate that your named credential is at least working use it for the SF REST API

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredtional_name/services/data/v36.0');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(30000);
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('Response Body===========' + res.getBody());
```

**Note** As sfdxfoc pointed out: You're using the Generate Authentication Header feature, so you shouldn't be setting your own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59638/discussion-between-sfdcbat-and-eric).