# Retrieve Org's API Usage and Data Storage Programmatically?

Tags: api, data

I'm new to Programming and Salesforce. I had to retrieve the API Usage and Data Storage of the org programmatically. Is this even correct?

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
String sysov = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI('/services/data/v37.0/limits/'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a callout, you can use the HttpRequest class.

It looks like this:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(
    Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+
    '/services/data/v43.0/limits');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

You can check [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) for more information.

Comment: Your code works. That's when my class is not scheduled. Now, I had to schedule it to retrieve those details every 2 hours. How to get around with your code if it's inside a scheduled class? I need to make this a package and install to client orgs. Will it be possible?

Comment: @cookie Asynchronous code naturally doesn't have a session ID. You'd have to have each client set up a Named Credential back in to Salesforce. Try looking at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/176844) for a quick description of how it's done (and there's a link to a blog post where someone did that).

Comment: I have checked the blog post and tried what he did. Unfortunately, my Authentication Status is still pending unlike his which has the "Authenticated as <his email>". How does this Status change from Pending to being Authenticated?

Comment: @cookie You have to complete the authentication process. There's a thing on the named credential when you're editing saying "launch login flow after saving." You need to complete the process to make the named credential active.

Comment: Oh right. However, I'm getting this error "error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration" when saving even when my Connected APP Callback URL is the same with NamedCredential URL. Or maybe my URL is not valid https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token ?

Comment: My own Salesforce Instance URL does not work as Connected APP Callback URL and NamedCredential URL either.

Comment: I was able to be authenticated. I had to use the Callback URL stated from the generated callbackURL in my AuthProvider setup. Thanks